# Is the Acer Aspire Z5771 Windows 8 compatible?

Tags: windows-8-preview, acer-aspire

I'm looking at the Acer Aspire Z5771 as a possible desktop system to develop Windows 8 Metro applications on.  Since it has a multi-touch screen, how compatible is it with Windows 8?

What things should I look out for when considering possible Windows 8 compatibility for a desktop machine.

TIA,
Paolo

Answer (score 2):

**Generally**, most Windows 7 compatible machines are Windows 8 compatible.

If the screen supports multi-touch, it should work with Windows 8.

Comment: @Moab his main question is the second sentence. Thanks.